# Popup on touch of annotation iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, annotations

I have developed some code that displays annotation on the map. Now the problem is I have multiple annotations ( of my 10 products ) on one point of map. If user touches on the this point, I want to open one new popup in which 10 products are displayed. User can choose any product from popup ! I have no idea how to implement it. How can i ?

Can anyone help me ?

This is the matter of particular point. Can anyone say how to implement in case of nearby points ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this :

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/gikanimatedcallout

Comment: It works for iPhone, I tried to implement it on an app in iPhone and it works just fine.